# How to use data annotations to do units conversion in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-annotations

I have for example a view model

```
class Measurements : ViewModelBase {

    [Units(Meters)]
    double Length { ... }

    [Units(Degrees)]
    double Angle{ ... }
}
```

then in my XAML I would like something like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Length DisplayUnits="Millimeters"}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Length DisplayUnits="Radians"}"/>
```

and the system will make sure the textbox edits in the display units
and converts to the correct view model units.

I will also have a globals settings singleton object

```
class Settings : ViewModelBase {

    AngleUnitsEnum AngleDisplayUnits { ... }
    LengthUnitsEnum LengthDisplayUnits { ... }

}
```

which can be updated any time and all the textboxes should update
their display immediately.

Before I go reinvent the wheel, the axel, the engine block and the
comfy seats can anybody suggest if there is a simple way to achieve
this built in?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach perhaps is to use value converters (classes that implement `IValueConverter`, and are declared as a resource in your `XAML`). You could use a binding on your Textbox that get fired on LostFocus, so when you leave the `TextBox` your `ValueConverter` fires and does the conversion